# T2DM diagnosis vs disorder due to T2DM diagnosis?

Tags: medications, infection, diabetes, type-2-diabetes, type-1-diabetes

I have a database of diabetic patients. Mostly 80 % are T2DM patients. Now I would like to identify the T2DM patients based on their conditions reported. I mean when patients visit hospital (diabetic specialist clinic), they report/record their conditions.

Is it normal to consider items like `Type 2 diabetes mellitus with Ulcer` or `Rubeosis iridis with T2DM` or `Retinopathy with T2DM` etc as diagnosis for T2DM?

I thought we should only look for `Type 2 diabetes mellitus` in condition table because this to me seems like a diagnosis for T2DM. But can the above (or similar) items be considered for T2DM diagnosis and if yes, why? Because I see it is being considered

Can you help me understand this?

Comment: I think this is a pretty complex question that can only be answered knowing your research goals and with deep knowledge of the data source you have.

Comment: My objective is apply a rule based phenotype algorithm (set of conditions) to identify my T2DM patients as T2DM.

Comment: This is what I am trying to do  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/projects/gap/cgi-bin/GetPdf.cgi?id=phd004998.1

Comment: Well, the patient might still have the complication but not having anymore an A1C high enough to be considered T2DM. A T2DM diagnosis is valid if currently, the patient has Glycated haemoglobin above the level defined by your local regulations

Comment: Ok, I'd be cautious in advising your further. I think this is really something you need to address with your research team, especially if these sorts of entries are confounded with your predictors. Analyzing a different data set, I ran into similar issues with dementia diagnoses and ultimately had to explain to the team that there was no way we could analyze dementia in that dataset because the codes were far too unreliable (the problem wasn't that people coded as having dementia lacked dementia, but far more lacked dementia codes that should have had them).

Comment: All your 3 highlighted diagnoses clearly word out T2DM, so it's obviously T2DM. But if the diagnosis says only "diabetes mellitus" without saying is it type 1 or type 2, there's no way you can say it just from the complications.

Comment: Hi, a quick question. I see that treatment path for T2DM is `(lifestyle changes -> non-insulin medication -> insulin)`. May I know why is this followed? And why not `(lifestyle changes -> insulin -> non-insulin medication)`. I understand it's always best to make lifestyle changes rather than taking medication. so i have left the 1st item as is (lifestyle changes). But why can't 2 and 3 be swapped?

Comment: What could it mean when it is swapped? I see that in my database, few patients have insulin medication first and later followed by non-insulin medication.

Comment: Please read something about diabetes 2. You can't really work with this without knowing the basics. There's an excess of insulin in T2DM already, unlike in T1DM. But you should really study this first.

Comment: @Jan - Yes the terms that I highlighted contain `T2DM`. let's say for an example, I have a patient's condition record during his hospital journey (multiple visits). I see that he has 1 condition of `Type 2 diabetes mellitus` and another condition of `Eye disorder due to Type 2 diabetes mellitus` and another condition of `Type 2 diabetes with ulcer`. So now in this case, are all the conditions called as `T2DM diagnoses`. I thought T2DM diagnosis would only mean pure T2DM

Comment: @Jan - I understand your point about Insulin. But my question is when I actually see patients starting with Insulin and as days progress they take T2DM drugs like sitagliptin etc. So does this mean the patient has developed T2 as well after T1

Comment: The diagnosis is T2DM. With experience you'll realize that in practice not everything is so formally written as you expect. The diagnoses above are shortened descriptions of a T2DM + complication. So, a patient has a "T2DM" (this is the diagnosis) and a doctor believes that the (stomach) ulcer is associated with diabetes. As Bryan Krause mentioned above, there may be more informality in the written documents than you would expect.

Comment: A Patient with severe T2DM may initially be treated with insulin, but when lifestyle changes (weight loss, diet) help, he/she may no longer need insulin, but only oral medications. But this is just a theory; to really know, you would need to know what actually happened.